# How to retrieve value from tag,SOAP

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, nsstring

I am using SOAP , and got this returnString.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<result>
<a>dddddddddddd5</a>
<b>ccccc+</b>
<c>hi</c>
</result>
```

How can I retrieve the value from tag  and assign it to a NSString??

Comment: Any chance you took a look at one of the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it running this works NSString *UIDFromXml = [returnUID stringBetween:@"" and:@""];. thanks for the response –

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse the XML response you get … I would recommend you to use an external library for this problem. Give this article a shot to decide which one you want to use: [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

A really great article about using SOAP services with iOS is this one: [Working with iOS and SOAP](http://blog.exadel.com/2011/03/working-with-ios-and-soap/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: got it running this works NSString *UIDFromXml = [returnUID stringBetween:@"<DID>" and:@"</DID>"];. thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

you must parse the result to get the value
i advice you this lib to parse your result [GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) 
as i know there is no official client  soap  library in objective C

Comment: got it running this works  NSString *UIDFromXml = [returnUID stringBetween:@"<DID>" and:@"</DID>"];. thanks for the response